# how to create some (empurpling,glow and another face effects) cocos2d or filters

Tags: ios, animation, image-processing, filter

I want to add animation and when finish animating add some image effects but not all image for example only eyes or cheek

How can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cocos2d Effects](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/introduction-to-cocos2ds-effects/) that are special kind of action. They can be used to make face look e.g. fattier, distorted etc. To apply a **glow effect** you would need to play with blending as described in [this](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/opengl-blending/#post-11195) thread. Similar solution can be applied to achieve a [**shine effect**](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/how-to-whiten-ccsprite-shine-effect/).